# Universal app approach to organize UIbutton programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uibutton

let us say we programmatically build UIbutton for each words like [image: picture below.]
 "What" "is" "your" "name" are all UIbutton built programmatically. What is the best way to approach the UI layout, so we auto wrap the long sentence into next "line", like the location of "Davis" "Maxfield".

The sentence of each questions or answer will be vary dynamically. Don't think we can pre-calculated the number of UIButton needed and use the Storyboard to build it(NOT 100% sure, willing to learn if it is possible)

The only option left for me is calculate the screen size programmatically, then build the UIButton size based on the screen size. I do would like to auto increase the size of the each word as big as possible(iPad user) since I plan to use this app to help some senior people to learn English, which they like bigger font size.  I have hardcoded to "fix" the issue, (as below)[image]

But hardcoded is not a good ideal if we have a super long sentence, which will build something like this [image]. I found "vertical stack view", but not sure if we can take advantage of it. and build the UI more elegantly. Thank you.

Comment: Is that a list?. If it is you can use TableView with `UItableViewAutomaticDimensions`.

Comment: Look into `UICollectionView`

Comment: If the purpose of UIButton is to get click event of particular word then why do not you take attributed text (Just take UILabel or UITextview) and get text touch event.

Comment: @indrajit yes. the UIButton is to trigger some actions like definition, pronunciation and translation. For Now it may just pronunciation. Do you have a good example to demo using  attributed text  to play a mp3 file( since I don't want the regular pronunciation for it)

Comment: Amm, so you want just action event (click or touch on particular word). let me make small demo, Will catch u in 3-4 hrs

Comment: @indrajit Do you have a change to find a  a demo ?